# How to receive incoming call with TwilioXamarinBindings Twilio.Voice.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, twilio, voip

I'm new to Twilio and expected there to be a Xamarin SDK for iOS and Android but apparently there isn't.  I have been working with https://github.com/dkornev/TwilioXamarinBindings for native libraries but cannot seem to find any help with getting an incoming (to the iOS/Android app) call.  I'm not sure if there's a tutorial somewhere explaining exactly how to route the call to a specific device but I can't see it....

So, can somebody explain the procedure, do I need Apple APN and if so how is it acheived in Xamarin Forms?

I haven't found anything for incoming calls to Xamarin apps via VOIP but all outgoing is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'm not familiar with those bindings but looking at the sample application that is included in the repo it looks like in iOS there is a method called `AcceptWithDelegate` that you call to accept an incoming Twilio Voice call.

https://github.com/dkornev/TwilioXamarinBindings/blob/master/sample/Twilio.Voice.Sample.iOS/TwilioVoiceHelper.cs#L131-L136

The [binding source](https://github.com/dkornev/TwilioXamarinBindings/blob/d676337b633c3bc969d0f101e0bb7de5163b4f81/source/Twilio.Voice.iOS/ApiDefinition.cs#L163-L165) appears to map this to the iOS SDK's `acceptWithDelegate` function:

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/voice/releases/2.0.7/docs/Classes/TVOCallInvite.html#//api/name/acceptWithDelegate:

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Devin, I'll take a look through the documentation as I'm unsure as to the process of initiating the call via APN.

Comment: @user1919214 This so late, but just wanted to share that I wrote a blog https://medium.com/@san.thanki/callkit-pushkit-twilio-with-xamarin-83553f93be86 and with end-to-end sample using twilio and iOS call kit to receive/handle incoming call using Xamarin.forms, may be it help.